# how to get content from a TEXT column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query, datatypes

maybe dumb question but if I have a table with a MEDIUMTEXT column how do I query that table and see what the actual content is? eg `SELECT text FROM PRIMARY_TEXT WHERE id = 1`. What I get back now is `[object Object]`.

thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**
my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `primary_text` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `card_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `card_id` (`card_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `source_text_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`card_id`) REFERENCES `cards` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=082b6e4683e0ed50d560a1eb7e8af926 for a test, with output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object Object]` sounds like an "Object" was inserted instead of a "string".  Such can happen if you are not careful in JavaScript and several other languages.

Comment: The text '[object Object]' is a string, not an object, that's why a string was inserted, not an object.